# Dynamically set javascript object key-values using variable chaining

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically add object values using a `type` variable.

Here is a working example without using a `type` variable:

```
let test = {
    'details': {
        'address': {
            'line1': '13 test st'
        }
    }
}

test['details']['address']['line1'] = '18 test st'

console.log('test', test)
```

The `test` variable successfully has a new `line1` of `'18 test st'`. However, I want to be able to use a `type` variable, which fails:

```
let type = `['details']['address']['line1']`

`${test}${type}` = '20 test st'
```

How can this be achieved? I know my syntax is incorrect but I can't find anywhere that defines how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract key name and then using `array#reduce` iterate through each key and create object and for the last key assign your value.

```js
const test = {},
      value = '18 test st',
      path = `['details']['address']['line1']`;
path.match(/\w+/g).reduce((o, key, i, a) => {
  o[key] ||= {};
  if(i === a.length - 1) {
    o[key] = value;
  }
  return o[key];
}, test);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: OP wants to set the value to `'20 test st'`

Answer (score 1):

You can store the key in an array and access it like below.

```js
const test = {
  details: {
    address: {
      line1: "13 test st",
    },
  },
};

console.log(test);

const type = ["details", "address", "line1"];

test[type[0]][type[1]][type[2]] = "20 test st";

console.log(test);
```